# video doesn't play o FB wall

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, video, share

I need to share my videos on facebook and make them play on Fb wall. I added all meta tags which are required for that, below you can see them:

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="myAppID" />
<meta property="og:url" content="Post Url">
<meta property="og:title" content="Post Title" />
<meta property="og:image" content="Post Image" />
<meta property="og:type" content="video" />
<meta property="og:video" content="Amazon Https Url(format is mp4)" />
<meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="Amazon Https Url(format is mp4)"/>
<meta property="og:video:height" content="209" />
<meta property="og:video:width" content="400" />
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis at metus non odio viverra interdum in a nibh. In vulputate luctus dolor. Aenean quam orci, consequat quis gravida id, finibus nec nisl. Vestibulum dictum tincidunt congue. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vivamus commodo sapien enim, in pulvinar magna vehicula nec. Vestibulum posuere leo eu viverra dictum." /> 
<meta property="og:image:width" content="400" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="209" />
```

When I share video post look is ok, I see thumbnail, title and domain over thumbnail. This is good. But after sharing when I click on play button, video doesn't play, it disappears.(Please see attached screenshot)

My videos are hosted in Amazon S3. Is only video link enough for making video play on facebook wall?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the `og:video:type` to mp4, once your video is mp4, not flash:

```
<meta property="og:video:type" content="video/mp4" />
```

You also should change the first URL to `http`, not `https`, so you'll have something like that:

```
<meta property="og:video" content="http://s3.amazon...etc">

<meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://s3.amazon...etc">
```

Hope to have helped! If I did, please mark the answer as useful or correct... Thanks and good luck!

You might want give a look at this [article](http://garethhooper.com/2012/01/28/how-to-embed-your-own-videos-on-facebook-using-the-facebook-like-and-share-buttons/), where the author explains this topic better.